# SQL two tables with different month values. Getting one result set for all the months

Tags: sql, select

If I have two tables like this:

Table1

```
Month
1
3
```

Table 2

```
Month 
1
4
```

How do I get the following result set?
Result Set

```
Month
1 
3
4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT [Month]
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT [Month]
FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`UNION`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator like this:

```
SELECT Month FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT Month FROM Table2
```

The SQL UNION operator combines two or more SELECT statements and produces a single result **with unique values**.

Comment: Won't you get Month 1 in both SELECTs and in the UNION resultset?

Comment: I think not with `UNION` which return unique values unlike `UNION ALL`

Comment: @DOK: No, `UNION ALL` will return full set. The `UNION` just returns the unique values.

Answer (score 4):

You will want to use a UNION to combine the results into a single set.

```
SELECT Month
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT Month
FROM Table2
```

By default `UNION` only grabs distinct values, therefore your exact result.  If you wanted duplicate values you could use `UNION ALL` which would show month 1 in your example twice.

Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) that shows the differences as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION`:

```
SELECT month FROM table1 UNION SELECT month FROM table2
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT Month FROM Table 1 UNION Select Month FROM Table 2 should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
declare @ temptable table( months varchar(10) )
inserto into @temptable(months)
select distinct Month from Table1

inserto into @temptable(months)
select distinct Month from Table2

select disticnt * from @temptable
```

Maybe there is a better way?